# SQL Server Isnull Returning 1900-01-01 when field is null

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, datetime

The following piece of code is returning 1900-01-01 when the DOB field is null. I wanted (and expected) it to return an empty string ('') but it's not. How should I proceed to get my desired results?

```
isnull(convert(date,DOB,1),'')
```

Comment: You're mixing data types up too much. Essentially what you're doing with `NULL` dates is saying `SELECT CAST('' AS DATE)`. What data type is `DOB`?

Comment: it's a varchar data type that I am converting to date

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't get an empty string because you're returning the `DATE` value type from `ISNULL`.

Per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15), `ISNULL`

> **Returns the same type as check_expression.** If a literal NULL is
> provided as check_expression, returns the datatype of the
> replacement_value. If a literal NULL is provided as check_expression
> and no replacement_value is provided, returns an int.

If you're checking whether or not the value is `NULL`, there is no need to convert it to a date, unless you wanted to return a date value (which you don't seem to).

Instead, use:

```
SELECT ISNULL( DOB , '')
```

Which will return

```
''
```

if the value is `NULL`.

A `NULL` date is `NULL` (no value). An empty string, on the other hand, evaluates to `0`, which in SQL Server is implicitly an integer representing the number of days since `1900-01-01`.

Answer (score -4):

This will convert the NULL date to space. The application layer (Excel) handles space fine

```
ISNULL (CONVERT(varchar(50), w.TRANSACTIONDT, 120), '')  as wTRANSACTIONDT
```

Answer (score -4):

Just create a view

CREATE VIEW test_view
AS
SELECT case when year(DOB)<=1900 then null else DOB end as DOB,sometext,id from test;

and then use it instead original table: select * from test_view